# Create empty raster with dimensions, pixels size and CRS of another raster in R

Tags: raster, r, terra

I am trying to create an empty raster layer and I want this empty raster to have the same dimensions, pixel size and CRS based on another raster, but no pixel values.

I am getting errors when I try to do this, based on what I am trying. For example:

```
library(terra)
cr = rast(path/test.tif) # extract CRS, pixel size, dimensions

**Try 1**

er_crs = crs(cr)
er_dim = dim(cr)
er_res = res(cr)

er = rast(`dim<-`(er_dim),
          `res<-`(er_res),
          `crs<-`(er_crs))

Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'rast': 1 argument passed to 'dim<-' which requires 2

**Try 2**

er_crs = crs(cr)
er_res = res(cr)
er_row = nrow(cr)
er_col = ncol(cr)

er = rast(`nrow<-`(er_row),
          `ncol<-`(er_col),
          `res<-`(er_res),
          `crs<-`(er_crs))

Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'rast': unable to find an inherited method for function ‘nrow<-’ for signature ‘"numeric", "missing"’
```

I have tried few more times but I am getting more errors.

Here is the raster:

```
cr = rast(ncols=23, nrows=43, nlyrs=1, xmin=583280, xmax=593860, ymin=1006020, ymax=1025800, names=c('test'), crs='EPSG:7767')
```

Comment: I'm curious to know why you are trying to use `nrow<-`  in your calls like `rast(\`nrow<-\`(er_row),...`.  This isn't how you pass named parameters in R, you have to use the equals sign: `rast(nrow=er_row,...)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass a SpatExtent (extent) object to terra::rast to create a new empty raster with the same extent. If you also provide the resolution argument that will address the resolution, row, column parts as well.

```
library(terra)

( r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")) )

( er <- rast(ext(r), resolution=res(r)) ) 
  crs(er) <- crs(r)
```

Comment: The crs can be defined as a parameter within the `rast` function so you could run this as a one liner if needed. 

`er <- rast(ext(r), resolution=res(r), crs = crs(r)) `

Comment: I tend to assign the csr after-the-fact because not all methods in `terra::rast` accept the csr argument (eg., list, character). However, in this case, proving the argument is certainly more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification there. Learned something new!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to make a copy of your original raster and set all values to `NA`:

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.6.33

r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 90, 95, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#> extent      : 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> source      : elev.tif 
#> name        : elevation 
#> min value   :       141 
#> max value   :       547

s <- r
values(s) <- NA
s
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 90, 95, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#> extent      : 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> source(s)   : memory
#> name        : elevation 
#> min value   :       NaN 
#> max value   :       NaN
```

As you can see, dimensions, resolution and crs are all the same.

Comment: do that with s <- rast(r)

Answer (score 1):

Another call to `rast()` does this.

```
library(terra)
## has values
r <- rast(matrix(1:12, 3))

## has no values (not even NA)
rast(r)
```

It was the same in principle with 'raster', but the details are very different.